# Getting null value for the objects while creating alert

Tags: alert, grafana-alerts

Hi I want to create a simple alert in grafana. Getting `null` value for the objects while creating alert.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

I could use some more information, as Chris states in the comments, but your question is actually one I've tried myself and wondered why the H the alert wasn't triggered.

There can be multiple solutions to this (I need more info, if I should help you more specifically):

1. Try to change the time-condition, which you've set now to "now-10m". I myself haven't had any issues with "-10m", but the less range from now (fx "now-1m") the bigger the risks for insecurities. 
   Therefore try and change it to "now-1h" and see if there still isn't any data (don't mind if the alert isn't triggered, just check if there is data).
2. Check if your query is correct (and most importantly - post it here, so we can help you better. Are you fx using template variables in your query? If so, then it won't trigger an alarm.
3. What version of Grafana are you using? If not the newest, then try to update.

Other than that - what does the logs say? Are you sure, you are getting data returned when running it on the source itself (fx the database?)

Please try these steps and if none of them work, I will gladly try to help you further (given that you provide some more information).

Comment: Thanks for writting ..i have changed time correction (1step) but still having same issue.i am using Grafana v6.5.2. as i am fetching data from snmp, where data is written in influx db, when i run snmpwalk to get data from that particular mib,  getting this error  Wrong Type (should be INTEGER): i guess there is some issue with mibs .CISCO-UNIFIED-COMPUTING-COMPUTE-MIB::cucsComputeMbPowerStatsConsumedPower.14569438 = Wrong Type (should be INTEGER): STRING: "288.000000"